# TestNg installation problem even though getting link from updated testng.org

Tags: eclipse, testng, eclipse-2020-06

Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/content.xml

Am getting this message while trying to install testng getting the updated link from testng.org downloads....

Answer (score 1):

**Please use the below step to install it on eclipse:**

**Install via Eclipse Marketplace**

Go to the TestNG page on the Eclipse Market Place and drag the icon called "Install" onto your workspace.

**OR**

**Install from update site**

- Select Help / Install New Software...
- Enter the update site URL in
  "Work with:" field: Update site for release:
  https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site.
- Make sure the check
  box next to URL is checked and click Next.
- Eclipse will then guide
  you through the process.

**Ref:** https://testng.org/doc/download.html

[image]

**Main update site URL: https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site**

[image]

[image]

**Also you can use the below link directly, if you want to install a specific version:**

Versioned update site URL:

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.4.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.3.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.2.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.1.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.0.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/6.14.3

[image]

Comment: @PallaviBS If this able to solve your problem, kindly mark it as 'answer'. so that others can take benefit from this.